# assigning string using javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts2

I have a web app that pulls a string from the database. This string can be very long sometimes and may contain carriage returns and double quotes.

My problem now is after I pull this string in the back end and try to display it on the jsp page using javascript, I encounter some problems. (btw, the app uses struts2)

first approach:

```
<% String myString = (String)request.getAttribute("myVar"); %>
<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
     document.getElementById('myTextArea').value =' <%= myString %> '; //this uses single quote
</script>
```

problem:

this can't display very long strings (1000+ char) and strings with carriage returns but can display string that contain double quotes.

second approach:

```
<% String myString = (String)request.getAttribute("myVar"); %>
<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
     document.getElementById('myTextArea').value = " <%= myString %> "; //this uses double quotes
</script>
```

problem:

this can't display strings with double quotes and strings with carriage returns, but it can handle very long strings (1000+ chars).

How do I display the string that I pulled which contains double quotes and carriage returns that are very long???

Thanks,

Comment: Don't write it out as a plain string - any JS metacharacters in the raw string will just cause JS syntax errors. Write it out as a JSON string, which will guarantee that it's syntactically valid JS code.

Comment: is there any way to handle this using plain javascript?

Comment: this has nothing to do with "plain javascript", this is a problem of how you're causing your server-side code to output javascript strings. If the server outputs strings into a JS code block with syntax error, the script will not even run.

Comment: @user1174960 can't you use a simple struts2 tags and than can use javascript like document.getElementByID()? IMHO when struts2 providing a very clean way to access values in your JSP why you polluting  you JSP with `(String)request.getAttribute("myVar")`;

Comment: I'm still very new to struts and javascript, so I'm not aware of the best practices yet. I've only looked at some sample codes and went on from there. Plus I was given a tight deadline.

Comment: @user1174960: can you describe what you want to do here?? also when you comment on some one response use @ along with his/her name, else the person will not able to know you have commented

Answer (score 0):

why use javascript to do this, why not do this:

```
<pre>
 <%= myString %> 
</pre>
```

Comment: I'm actually assigning the value of the string to a textarea, I just used the document.write() for explanation.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, you should just use JavaScript Object Notation (JSON)

[Relevant Java Docs](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#toString%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

Ok. let's say your server side string is `Beam me down, chief O'Brien`. Your code is going to produce this output which gets sent to the client browser:

```
document.write('Beam me down, chief O'Brien');
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-----one string
                                      ^^^^^ non-string
                                           ^^^ new string
```

Note the unbalanced quotes. You may have a nice normal string, but it's syntactically illegal javascript, because `Brien` is not known to JS. Then the closing quote in your output code causes the training `);` to become part of a new unterminated string literal.

So you've got two syntax errors, causing the entire JS code block to be killed/ignored.

As well, since you're just immediately doing `document.write` on it, you're in effect simply tryign to write that string into the document at that point in the document's flow, so you could just have:

```
<%= myString %>
```

and get the same effect, without having to worry about JS syntax problems.

If you absolutely HAVE to write it out via Javascript, then output the string as a JSON string literal, which is guaranteed to be syntactically valid Javascript.

Comment: Sorry for the bad example. I actually wanted the value to be assigned to a text area.

Comment: Then `<textarea><%= myString %></textarea>` would work. there's no need to get JS involved.

Comment: what if I want the value to be assigned to the textarea when a user clicks a checkbox or something?

Comment: output it to a hidden div and use some JS to copy it that way. saves you the trouble of having to turn it into valid JS code.

Answer (score 0):

After seeing you code. i Don't think you need to use JavaScript at all.IF you goal is to prep-populate your textfield on page load with the defined values in your action class you need not do do this long process.

I am assuming that `myVar` is a property in your Strtuts2 Action class and you have respected getter and setter in your Action class, so in order to fill the textfiled in your JSP page just use Struts2 tags and it will do the rest of work for you which includes

1. Fetching the value of myVar from Action.
2. Converting the value in to String (data conversion)

you need to put following code in your JSP

```
<s:textfield name="myVar" value="%{myVar}/>
```

`value="%{myVar}` will do the work for you as it will fetch the value from the Request (Value-Stack) and will fill the text field with the desired value.

For above code to work include S2 tag library in your JSP page and you are good to go.These tags code will get converted to simple HTML and you can do anything you want to do which can be done with HTML+Java-Script

Answer (score 0):

<%= myString %> should work. If you want to have some effects, you can save this data in some hidden text and populate at the time needed. I hope you are not getting confused with that at <% =myString%> will execute when you will be running this js method. It will be run at the time the response on the jsp is getting created.